# Drop NaN values but not the entire column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given this pandas df:

```
Col A.   Col B.   Col C.   
1         a        12
2         s        21
NaN       s        Nan
7         a        Nan
```

I would like to get this:

```
Col A.   Col B.   Col C.   
1         a        12
2         s        21
7         s        
          a
```

Comment: how do you align index by doing so? do you just need to replace the NaN by a blank string?

Comment: Hi. No, I don't need to replace NaN by a blank string, I would like to drop those NaN but not the entire column that contains NaN. If possible.. Right now I'm working with blank replacement but it would be nice to do the other thing.

Comment: can you test `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df.stack().groupby(level=1).agg(list).to_dict(),orient='index').T` and let me know

Comment: @anky_91 It's better! Now the NaN are None but it still better for my task. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
out = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df.stack().groupby(level=1).agg(list)
       .to_dict(),orient='index').T)
print(out)
```

---

```
   Col A. Col B. Col C.
0      1      a     12
1      2      s     21
2      7      s   None
3   None      a   None
```